# Updating $scope without ng-click and sorting the array dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update the view dynamically when a new record is added via websockets. The newest record (it'll have the highest ID by default) should be at the bottom, but it gets added randomly. I couldn't find why it happens.

```js
angular.module('Persistence').controller("PersistenceController", [
  "$scope",
  "$http",
  "$filter",
  "$timeout",
  "$mdDialog",
  "$sce",
  function ($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout, $mdDialog, $sce) {
    $scope.records = [];
    $scope.sortById = 'id';
    var socket2 = io.connect('192.168.1.100:3001');

    socket2.on('newInformation', function (data) {
      $scope.records.push({
        title: data.data.title,
        id : data.data.id,
        name: data.data.name
      });

      $scope.$apply();

    });    
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Persistence" ng-controller="PersistenceController">
  <div ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy : sortById">
    <div>{{record.id}}</div>
    <div>{{record.title}}</div>
    <div>{{record.name}}</div>        
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your variable names are wrong. Change the place of `title` with `id` in record object.

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız thanks, I changed it but still no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your sortId in a right way. By using `id : data.data.id` instead of `id : data.data.title`. Your attribute mapping is wrong, thats all. Ensure that your sort attribute is the **same data-type** as your other items.

```
$scope.records.push({
    id : data.data.id,
    title: data.data.title,
    name: data.data.name
});
```

Take a look at this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20wkkf6z/)**.

Comment: I changed it but it is still getting added in the wrong order. I add 8, then 12, then 9. It should be 8-9-12, but what I get is 12-8-9.

Comment: @salep It works as expected. I added a demo fiddle. Maybe there is something wrong with your Id's? Ensure that your Id is the same datatype than the others. Take look over here - http://jsfiddle.net/qhwu9kro/ if your new record is added with an string as `Id` the sorting error begins.

Comment: You are right, the problem was its type. I was sending it as a string. Thanks a lot.